# How to Retrieve names of stored procedures in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Is there any way to retrieve the names of the stored procedures by some SELECT from the system table or any system SP?

I need to retrieve all the stored procedure names with their signatures (if possible) or just names. I know how to do that in MySql, but similar queries don't work (of course, since all the system DBs named differently).

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT  name
FROM    sys.objects
WHERE   type = 'P'
```

The ANSI way (which will work on both MySQL and MS SQL) is:

```
SELECT  ROUTINE_NAME
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE   ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this would work in MySQL but it works in MS SQL.

exec sp_stored_procedures

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE type=’p’
```